# How exactly does Dijkstra's alg reconstruct path?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

So this question might sound dumb and obvious but for some reason, I feel like there's more to just saving the current visited node to a prev list, (like explained on [Dijkstra's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)) before marking the neighbor with the shortest tentative distance the next current node. Can someone please explain how exactly Dijkstra's algorithm reconstructs the shortest path? ty in advance

Comment: When going backward from the destination, you can always easily reconstruct which node comes next because difference in distance has to match the edge between them. If there are multiple nodes that fulfill this condition, there are multiple shortest paths.

Comment: through reverse recursion.

Answer (score 0):

As you visit each node you are going to keep track of minimum cost of reaching the current node. For this you have to implement a `min heap`. "min heap" is a concrete data structure of `priority queue`. MinHeap is a complete binary tree in which the value in each internal node is smaller than or equal to the values in the children of that node because every insertion re-arranges the elements based on the priority value.

[image]

You will be adding a pair of `(costOfSoFarVisitingNode,Node)` and min heap will sort the elements based on `costOfSoFarVisitingNode`, so in case having this in min heap:

```
(2,nodeA)
(5,nodeA)
```

when you pop the element, min heap will be poping the (2,nodeA) so you will be always on the shortest path and keep implementing breadth first search on shortest path.